# $lookup aggregation using variable

Tags: mongodb, lookup

Dears, I'm new with MongoDB and I can't resolve this problem.

I think is simple, however, is beyond me =(
If someone could help me I'd really thank you :)

Let's suppose I need to do a $lookup to a collection I still don't know the name. I got a lot of collections!! This example can give an ideia:

```
**Collection Books** {id, name, year, editor, *source*};
**Collection Category** {category_name, collection_name, *source*};

**Collection Cat_Romance** {*source*, main_guy, main_girl, theme, ...};
**Collection Cat_Thriller** {*source*, enigma, thriller, ...};
**Collection Cat_Adventure**;
**Collection Cat_Magic**, ....;
```

As you can see, each document inside *category* collection, presents differents informations.

The thing is, I'm creating a system who receives the name of the category, and I need to get back, the main infos of the book, and all infos in his respectively collection. Something like the code bellow:

```
db.books.aggregate([
   { $lookup : {
        from : "category",
        localField : "source",
        foreignField : "source",
        as : "category" }},
   { $unwind : "$category"},
   { $match : { 'category.category_name' : */romance/*}}
   { $project: { cat : '$category.collection_name'}}, 
   { $lookup : {
        from : "$$cat",
        localField : "source",
        foreignField : "source",
        as : "category_infos" }},
])
```

In this example, I want those books who belongs to the category *romance.*
As presented above in the query, I'm using the field *source* to aggregate the collections, and also, storing the name of the collection I want into the variable *cat*. This variable I want to use into the second $lookup to aggregate the correct collection.

Supposing I'm receive the entry: *romance*, the code should return something like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectID("XXXXX"),
    "name": "XXXX",
    "year": "XXXX",
    "editor": "XXXX",
    "category_infos" : {
           *source*: "YYY", 
           main_guy: "YYY",
           main_girl: "YYY",
           theme: "YYY",
           ....
    }
}
```

Well, I think the problem is explained. I really appreciate if someone could give me a light. I'm fighting with this is been some hours =(
If the code is not enoght, or in bad format, let me know.

I thank anyone in advanced for take a look and try to help =)

Comment: The collection name used cannot be dynamic, See [SERVER-22497](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-22497) for tracking. The only present workaround options are either executing a `$lookup` stage for every possible collection value, or a redesign of schema and storage to work within constraints. If you think you need this, then you should "probably" have a "type discriminator" field on a *single target collection* as opposed to storing in different collections.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunatelly, it ain't possible to do =(. I really appreciate your time. It seems like I didn't research as I should.